# Multiple 2 field in SQL Server stored procedure with insert

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Important note: for. exp. I have a, b and c columns in a SQL Server database and I want to insert this 3 value in SQL code so,

I want to insert a,b and multiple existent a and b field as c

How can I do this operation with stored procedure?

Comment: You want to multiple existent `a` and `b`?, can you clarify that?. Maybe post a sample of your data and the expected result

Comment: Do you mean something like this?  `UPDATE [Table] SET [C] = [A] * [B]`

Comment: create procedure multiple

@aint,
@b int,
@c int

as 


insert into table (a,b,c) values (@a,@b, @a*@b as @c)

Comment: In your procedure you are passing in `@c` but `@c` is supposed to be `@a *@b`? Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: think it a and b known value, but c will defined by a and b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see any reason for a `@c` variable at all.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MultiplY
  @a INT, @b INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.table(a,b,c) SELECT @a, @b, @a * @b;
END
GO
```